# Universal ring with zero matrix product is an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $n \geq 0$. The universal commutative ring which has two $n \times n$-matrices whose product is zero is
$$\textstyle R := \mathbb{Z}[(X_{ij})_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}, (Y_{ij})_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}] / \langle \sum_{k} X_{ik} Y_{kj} = 0 : 1 \leq i,j \leq n \rangle$$
So we have $2n^2$ generators and $n^2$ relations. If $n = 1$, then $R$ is just $\mathbb{Z}[u,v] / \langle uv = 0 \rangle$, hence not an integral domain.

**Question.** If $n > 1$, is $R$ an integral domain? And if not, can we at least show that $R$ is reduced?

Unfortunately I don't have an idea how to attack this problem, already for $n=2$. I vaguely remember that there are methods from algebraic geometry to show that a ring is an integral domain, but I don't know if this applies here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is never an integral domain since $XY = 0$ of course implies $\det(X) \det(Y) = 0$. We can show that these two determinants are not themselves zero by specializing $X$ and $Y$ to diagonal matrices with two diagonal entries $u, v$ satisfying $uv = 0$, reducing to the case $n = 1$.

I bet it's reduced but I'm not familiar with techniques for showing this. Maybe Grobner basis techniques can be used. **Edit:** I think Proposition 1.1 [here](https://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jan/mcs563s14/lec33.pdf) does it. As stated it only applies to ideals of polynomial rings over fields but I bet the proof can be adapted to work over $\mathbb{Z}$, maybe under the additional condition that the monomial ideal is generated by monic polynomials or something.

Comment: Thanks! Today it's not my day :/

Comment: @Martin: happens to the best of us!

Comment: More generally, I would expect the irreducible components to have to do with the different possibilities for the ranks of $X$ and $Y$.  For instance, when $n=3$, then at least over a field, at least one of $X$ and $Y$ must have rank at most 1, so the product of all their $2\times 2$ minors probably has to be $0$ in $R$ which gives some more zero divisors.

Comment: About the edit: if the ring $R$ is reduced when the ring of coefficients is $\mathbb Q$, then it is reduced when the ring of coefficients is $\mathbb Z$ since the second is contained in the first (which is a ring of fractions of the second by a multiplicative closed set consisting of non-zerodivisors).